# How to create a django form object for m2m through object

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a new django project with a m2m relationship that uses a 'through' object. Example:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='PhotoTag', related_name='tags', blank=True, db_index=True)

class PhotoTag(models.Model):
    photo= models.ForeignKey(Photo,db_index=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,db_index=True)
    added= models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I want users to be able to look through a screen full of photos and add/remove tags.  I am having some trouble designing the form/views for this.
I am thinking it's best to define a simple form object that creates the "PhotoTag" object, then create a ListView with a formset that contains all the PhotoTagForm objects, these forms may or may not POST to a view for live updating on the ListView, or have a single save button to save all the changes.

My question is what should this PhotoTagForm object look like? <strike>Do I want to use a ModelForm or create a regular form object?</strike>
Let's assume th form object inherits from Form not ModelForm.
The form needs to handle add (add tag to photo) and delete (remove tag from photo).

Comment: I don't see the point in defining a M2M through `phototag`. Seems like it just adds overhead to the problem. I think this problem would be better solved without defining your own `through` obj.

Comment: This is a dumbed down version, the through object has other fields in it, one  important one is the added field which tracks its creation so I can show 'recently added tags'

Comment: Whether to use a Form or ModelForm is primarily opinion based

Comment: I see. my understanding of ModelForm is that basically auto generates the save, is_valid, methods and automatically fadds fields based off on the model. It seems like this might not be of particular advantage for a through object since the number of fields are few, and validation would likely need to be customized manually (get valid tag object, create new ones when needed). I'll amend my question to specify only Form object.

Comment: @e4c5 do you know of any SO questions or other information that discuss using ModelForm vs Form for m2m through objects? I'm just curious. Could not find one myself.

Comment: you could still filter by recently added tags without the through object.

Comment: Thanks marcusshep. Again, this is just a striped down example. My question relates to creating a form object for this m2m relationship, which includes a through object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:

```
# Forms.py:
class PhotoTagForm(forms.Form):

    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),required=False)

    photo=None
    initial_tags={}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})
        if kwargs.get('photo'):
            self.study=kwargs['photo']
            self.initial_tags = set([l for l in self.photo.tags.all()])
            initial['tags'] = self.initial_tags
        forms.Form.__init__(self, *args, initial=initial)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):

        print(self.cleaned_data.keys())

        if 'tags' in self.changed_data:
            submitted_tags=set(self.cleaned_data.pop("tags",[]))
            removed_tags=self.initial_tags.difference(submitted_tags)
            added_tags = submitted_tags.difference(self.initial_tags)
            # do logic with removed and added tags to update the m2m model

# views.py
def EditPhotoTagView(request,pk):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST" and 'save' in request.POST.keys():
        form = PhotoTagForm(request.POST,photo=photo)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PhotoTagForm(photo=photo)

    return render(request, 'data/snippets/editm2m_form.html', {'form': form})

# urls.py
...
    url(r'^photo/(?P<pk>[0-9|.]+)/edit/tag$', EditPhotoTagView, name='photo_tag_form'),
...
```

The basic concept here that you first populate the form with the initial data for your m2m object, on POST you compare initial to the form.cleaned_data and perform the necessary logic to update the PhotoTag (create or delete the through object).  Here, I used the photo from the url pk, but you could also have a hidden input field with the photo.pk and use that to find the model during post.  I choose this way because it was easier to have the parent object as attribute then act directly upon it.
This should work for your listview if you post data to the URL, then update the listview.